# Flask DispatcherMiddleware Session

Tags: python, flask

I am developping Flask application.

I am using **DispatcherMiddleware** to combine my applications

```
app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware( app.wsgi_app, {'/health': subapp.wsgi_app} )
```

Is there a way that my main app and my subapp could share the same session ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the session by adding the same secret key to both applications.

Comment: I am also doing the same and using the same config file for both the apps  so that will have common configuration but still not able to share the same session. Is there any other settings to do ?

Comment: Do you have the same application secret key ?

Comment: Yes i have same secret key.

Comment: All right. I'll check it out very soon. In the meantime, please post if you find a solution.

Comment: Quite a bit late, but still a problem - at least for me.   Has anyone found an answer for this? I am trying to deploy a Gunicor Server incorporating a dispatcher middleware app in conjunction with an auth Service for securing some of the routes.